# Navigating to fragment doesn't Work - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was trying to open some fragment however the app keep crashing
I am wondering if it was possible to fix the issue that I got

```
class HomePage : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)

        val addMed = findViewById<Button>(R.id.addMedButton)
        val fragManager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        fragManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, addMed).commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the text of the code instead of using pictures? Then we don't have to retype everything manually to be able to help.

Comment: As I see you haven't defined the last parameter of `.add()`, which can be set to null https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a fragment, not a button.
Besides, if the button is found by id, it is already present in the activity.